# How to Google Content Experiments chooseVariation() with multiple tests on one page?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

According to [Google's analytics.js Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/experiments), if you have a single test you want to run on a page, the most straightforward method is to first, load the experiments script with the experiment ID specified:

```
<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js?experiment=YByMKfprRCStcMvK8zh1yw"></script>
```

Next, simply let Google pick the variation for you:

```
<script>
var variation = cxAPI.chooseVariation();
</script>
```

But what about the case where you have multiple tests on a single page? Perhaps you have a site-wide navigation test as well as an individual test on a single page? When visiting that page, there are 2 potential tests to run.

Google says that you can load the api without the experiment ID:

```
<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/cx/api.js"></script>
```

And then you can manually choose a variation for a particular experiment id:

var variation = cxApi.setChosenVariation(3, "YByMKfprRCStcMvK8zh1yw");

Okay so that seems to make sense. I suppose you could setup a random number generator (pick a random number between 1-3) in order to determine which variation to set for the visitor. But is it not possible to programmatically determine the number of variations in the test? Seems like that would be important information to be able to query if you are determining the method for setting the variation.

It doesn't appear you can pass an experiment ID to `chooseVariation()` either, or else that would work.

Comment: You'd need something more elaborate than a random number generator (you want to present always the same variation to a visitor, so you need to persist the chosen variation).  And the number of variations does not change at the runtime of an experiment, so somehow retrieving a number  from GA that will not change would have been a lot of trouble for  little result. I guess this isn't really designed to run multiple experiments on the same page (if you'd  run them at the same time it would invalidate the result in any case as you would not be able to tell which change led to what result).

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Regarding running multiple tests on a page, how would one ever do a test in something like your global navigation, or global header or footer or something that exists on every page of your site? If you did this type of test that would mean that you shouldn't do any other tests on your site since you will definitely have multiple tests on one page at least somewhere.